# Sending Text Messages via Twilio API using Java

Tags: java, twilio, phone-number

I registered with Twilio and have the following details from my account

Account SID  :  34 characters long
Auth Token : 34 characters long

I executed the below code with jar files for com.twilio.sdk loaded in classpath.
The program compiled and during run time I got error with "From Phone number".
I am not sure if I have to buy a phone number from Twilio or can I use my own phone number that I registered with Twilio ?

## Below is the code that I ran

```
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.instance.Account;
import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient;
import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestException;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.factory.MessageFactory;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.instance.Message;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

public class SmsSender {

    /* Find your sid and token at twilio.com/user/account */
    //public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "AC123";
   // public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "456bef";

    public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "ACXXXXXXXXXX";
    public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "08XXXXXXXXXX";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws TwilioRestException {

        TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

        Account account = client.getAccount();

        MessageFactory messageFactory = account.getMessageFactory();
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("To", "+15101234567")); // Replace with a valid phone number for your account.
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("From", "+5101234567")); // Replace with a valid phone number for your account.`enter code here`
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Body", "Hi, this is Devaraj, sending you message from Twilio"));
        Message sms = messageFactory.create(params);

    }
}
```

===================================================

### Error from executing the above code

Exception in thread "main" com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestException: The From phone number +14158141829 is not a valid, SMS-capable inbound phone number or short code for your account.
    at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestException.parseResponse(TwilioRestException.java:97)
    at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioClient.safeRequest(TwilioClient.java:493)
    at com.twilio.sdk.resource.list.MessageList.create(MessageList.java:70)
    at SmsSender.main(SmsSender.java:34)

Comment: You should not post your auth_token in the code, is a security risk. You'll have to invalidate your existing one.

Comment: The error description says it all: the number you're using to send the message has no sms capability. You need to get one that is sms capable.

Answer (score 1):

There could be two issues here.
1) Your phone number does not have SMS capability.
2) You could be using your Test Credentials while authenticating. If you are using [Test Credentials](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/test-credentials), Twilio will not charge your account, update the state of your account, or connect to real phone numbers.